# How do I mock a const method IN a component as part of an integration test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

So, I am doing an integration test with jest & tesing-library.
So, I have my "main component" called "Product" that brings in another component, lets call it "ProductListings".

In "ProductListings", i click on a div that calls a method IN the functional component. How do I mock that, to test it was called?

```
  test('Clicking div calls method', async () => {
     render(<Product />);
     // THIS div is in ProductListings component.. that is contained within Product component
     const divToClickAdd = await screen.findByTestId('myDivWithOnClick')
     user.click(divToClickAdd); // clicking this div fires the method
     // how to do this?
     expect.THE-MOCKED-FUNCTION-TO-HAVE-BEEN-CALLED 
 });
```

// this is what ProductListing looks like (psuedo). It is IN Products component, that I am integration testing.

```
 const ProductListing = () => {

   // I WANT TO MOCK THIS "fireTheAPI" in my test above.
   const fireTheAPI = () => {
      // do some stuff
   }

   return (
     <div onClick={() => fireTheAPI()} data-testId="myDivWithOnClick">this is a product listing item</div>

   )
}
```

See my issue. Bring in Parent component, that contains a "inner component, ProductListings, and I get a div from that, and click.. I need to mock that function IN it, "fireTheAPI"

btw, "Product" looks something like:

```
const Product = () => {
   return (
      <div>
        <WhateverComponent />
        <div>
            <ProductListings /> // <--- mock a function in here
        </div>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Can you have fireTheAPI be a function imported from another file? Then you can easily mock/stub/spy it.

Comment: I could, but it seems a lot of re-working to do that just to test a method. I'd have to pass in a dispatch etc. since its not a react component etc.... If I did, how do I mock it?

Comment: Currently it’s effectively a private function, so no. You could try to do monkey patching through libraries such as rewire, but it’s not ideal. In general having functions that need to be stubbed be imported modules/functions makes these things a lot easier. Maybe, you could somehow intercept the http requests via something like nock or mock-axios but it would depend on the implementation.

Comment: I ended up making it exportable, so I have it, just not sure how to actually mock it.

Comment: Are you now importing the function into the with jest mocking/stubbing mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what your function is doing.

In this instance, if you are expecting an API call, i would suggest using [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) to mock the API call.

It would look something like this

```
test('Your Test', () => {
    const scope = nock(YOUR_URL).get(YOUR_ENDPOINT).reply(200);

    const product = render(<Product />);
    const divToClickAdd = await product.findByTestId('myDivWithOnClick');

    act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(divToClickAdd);
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(scope.isDone()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

If you are expecting some DOM changes, you can go on to test that too.

IMO the integration tests should focus on the outcomes of the user actions, so rather than worrying about mocking a particular function, we should look towards attempting to mock (or test) the particular outcome of said function.

Comment: that is a good point, I wanted to test the "url" as the route changes, but I don't think I can get at the URL/location within a test... any ideas? That would be the outcome, the url changes.. so i couldn't figure that out, so I thought to verify the function was called.

Comment: @jamesemanon im not sure why are you unable to get the URL. maybe you could expand on your use case? 1 suggestion is you can consider doing something like reading your `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'` and set your base URL to `localhost`? would it work in your case?

Comment: well, in a test env there is no concept of "window" right.. so I culdn't get a window.location, I assume. I can check.

Comment: i dont believe you would need to do something like `window.location`. i find it odd that you'd have to do that. especially in a test env where you can mock it. is your function doing `window.location`?